# Find percentage of total of categories, sort from highest to lowest, preserve names of top 80% and renaming all others to 'other'

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset containing product brands in one column and features of the product as different columns as follows:

```
Brand      |Internal Memory|  Feature 2
-----------------------------------------
Apple      |16 GB          |    A
-----------------------------------------
Apple      |32 GB          |    B
-----------------------------------------
LG         |32 GB          |    C
-----------------------------------------
Samsung    |16 GB          |    B
-----------------------------------------
Samsung    |32 GB          |    A
-----------------------------------------
```

I am trying to do the following using python:

1) Find what percentage of the data belongs to each brand, in this case I would get something like:

```
Apple: 40% 
LG: 20%
Samsung: 40%
```

2) Sort them from highest to lowest frequency percentage

```
Apple: 40%
Samsung: 40%
LG: 20%
```

3) Add the frequency of each category to the next

```
Apple: 40%
Samsung: 80%
LG: 100%
```

4) Rename all categories after 80% in original dataset to obtain something like:

```
Brand      |Internal Memory|  Feature 2
-------------------------------------------
Apple      |16 GB          |    A
-------------------------------------------
Apple      |32 GB          |    B
-------------------------------------------
Other      |32 GB          |    C
-------------------------------------------
Samsung    |16 GB          |    B
-------------------------------------------
Samsung    |32 GB          |    A
-------------------------------------------
```

I have manually performed this operation but would love to do it in python

I am trying to do this using python 3 and pandas but I don't mind exploring different libraries or methods.

Comment: What have you tried to do? Pandas would be the package I would use to do something like this using their [groupby](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/groupby.html) methods.

Comment: Your goal is to only rename the last 20%? Or are those intermediate steps important to output as well?

Comment: @MatthewBarlowe I have successfully displayed a table showing count and correpsonding percentage of null values per column using the following code, I think some of it would apply to my problem but I haven't been able to do so.

null_values = [(col, (count_nans (col,df_to_analyze)), (count_nans(col, df_to_analyze)/len(df_to_analyze.index)*100)) for col in df_to_analyze.columns]
nulls_table = pd.DataFrame(null_values, columns = ('Columna', '# de Nulos', '% de Nulos'))
display(nulls_table)

Comment: @Erfan Main goal is to rename last 20%, it would be helpful to have intermediate steps displayed but are not necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To reproduce your steps, stepwise:

First we can map `value_counts` to our `Brand` column to get a percentage column:

```
df['Pct'] = df['Brand'].map(df['Brand'].value_counts(normalize=True).cumsum()) * 100

print(df)
     Brand Internal Memory Feature 2    Pct
0    Apple           16 GB         A   80.0
1    Apple           32 GB         B   80.0
2       LG           32 GB         C  100.0
3  Samsung           16 GB         B   40.0
4  Samsung           32 GB         A   40.0
```

After that we sort ascending with `sort_values` and reset our index

```
df.sort_values('Pct', inplace=True)
df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)

print(df)
     Brand Internal Memory Feature 2    Pct
0  Samsung           16 GB         B   40.0
1  Samsung           32 GB         A   40.0
2    Apple           16 GB         A   80.0
3    Apple           32 GB         B   80.0
4       LG           32 GB         C  100.0
```

After that we use `np.where` to conditionally fill `Brand` column with `Other` when the percentage is above 80:

```
df['Brand'] = np.where(df['Pct'] > 80, 'Other', df['Brand'])

print(df)
     Brand Internal Memory Feature 2    Pct
0  Samsung           16 GB         B   40.0
1  Samsung           32 GB         A   40.0
2    Apple           16 GB         A   80.0
3    Apple           32 GB         B   80.0
4    Other           32 GB         C  100.0
```

*If wanted*, you can drop the `Pct` column:

```
df.drop('Pct', axis=1, inplace=True)

print(df)
     Brand Internal Memory Feature 2
0  Samsung           16 GB         B
1  Samsung           32 GB         A
2    Apple           16 GB         A
3    Apple           32 GB         B
4    Other           32 GB         C
```

Comment: Thanks @Erfan! Seems to be exactly what I need, I'll try this out.

Comment: This solution worked perfectly, thanks again @Erfan